# how to add string and int into list box in buttons

Tags: java, vector, controller

i have some problems adding the int qty and string getname in listbox, the errors shown is somewhere in the middle jlist.add. any help please thanks!

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{                                         
    int id = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
    int qty = Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText());

    purchasecontroller.PurchaseProduct(id, qty);
    String getname = displaycontroller.SearchbyProductName(id);
    jLabel4.setText( "" + getname );
    jLabel3.setText("" + qty);
    jList1.add( "" + getname + "" qty );

    String getprice = displaycontroller.SearchbyProductPrice(id);
    int total = qty * Integer.parseInt (getprice);
    jLabel11.setText("" + total );
}
```

jList1.add("" + getname + "" + qty); i couldn't add thats the problem, the add is underline in red ! , it stated cannot find symbol

Comment: *What* error, specifically ?

Comment: What is the error? where exactly you are getting problem?

Comment: jList1.add("" + getname + "" + qty); i couldn't add thats the problem, the add is underline in red ! , it stated cannot find symbol

Comment: My bad. See @Reimeus answer. And [this tutorial](http://www.seasite.niu.edu/cs580java/JList_Basics.htm) for further info.

Answer (score 1):

The method `JList#add` is inherited from `Container` and does not allow you to add list elements to the component's model. You could use a `DefaultListModel` and add:

Java 1.6:

```
DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
JList list = new JList(listModel);
```

or Java 1.7:

```
DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
JList<String> list = new JList<>(listModel);
```

And:

```
listModel.addElement(getname + qty);
```

Comment: hi i tried but it still shows the error in  the addelement is underline in red ! , it stated cannot find symbol

Comment: hmm the first 2 row still highlighted in red and the add element also, i currently using netbeans and the listbox is created though pattern. need more help! thanks!

Comment: Did you import `DefaultListModel`? Also this code is has Java 7 syntax. What version of Java are you using?

Comment: i using older version netbeans 6.5.1 and java 6.0 ... how?